# Grails: How to dump an object's properties?

Tags: debugging, object, grails, cxf

**The setup**:

I am working on a Grails project that involves a lot of XML data transfers. We are using [Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org/)'s wsdl2java utility to generate the appropriate Java classes for the data formats.

We are caching some of the XML results and I need to find out if we have already cached a specific value at a specific point in the code (this has happened before).

**What I am looking for**:

A way to recursively dump random objects.

**What I have tried so far**:

1) println() -- This works well for hashmaps with basic types like Strings and Integers, but fails on generic Objects. It outputs the wsdl2java class's .toString() output, which resembles "com.company.services.provider.ADDRESS@2b1234ca1." Since this is an auto-generated class, we cannot replace that method easily.

2) The method outlined here: http://padcom13.blogspot.com/2009/12/groovy-dumping-objects-properties.html

I have wrapped this in a function and added it to the Object.metaClass in BootStrap.groovy. That allows it to be called recursively; however, only about half of the wsdl2java classes seem to inherit this function (verified with "println(obj.metaClass.metaMethods*.name.sort())"). None of them explicitly extend Object so I am lost.

**What is the cleanest way to recursively dump a random object's properties (preferably human-readable)?**

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

Many thanks to @dmahapatro and @JavaDev for their ideas. Here is the code that I am looking at right now:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
Object.metaClass.debug_dump = {
    JSON.use('deep')
    println(new JSON(delegate).toString())
}

...

session.cxfResult.debug_dump()
```

And this is the error that it produces when run:

```
Class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller can not access a member of class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl with modifiers "public". Stacktrace follows:
Message: Class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller can not access a member of class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl with modifiers "public"
```

This persists despite following the directions [of this individual on the Grails user list](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Convert-XMLGregorianCalendar-to-JSON-td1381176.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try use to render the object as JSON instead of using making it implicitly call toString().  I think it will render the structure of the object properly.

Comment: This feels hack-ish, but "variable as JSON" appears to render the structure properly. Why didn't I think of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Best possible option would be to render the object graph as **deep** [JSON](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/converters/JSON.html#use%28java.lang.String%29) or [XML](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/converters/XML.html#use%28java.lang.String%29) (cannot achieve with normal JSON or XML converters). 
Grails provides converters which effectively parses the object graph to a human readable form and is also useful for rendering response in webservice calls. Below is a detailed example as to how an object graph can be rendered either to a valid JSON Object or an XML.

**Use Case:**
Consider an object graph like:

`Parent` has `Child`, name, dob, age
`Child` has name, dob, age, `GrandChild` and has many `Qualities`
`GrandChild` has `Address` , blah, blah etc

**Sample**
[Detail example using domain objects with outputs can be found here](http://pastebin.com/3iRerzFF).
[Detail example using POGOs with outputs can be found here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5808109/)

**Key Area:**
The key area to focus on is the controller method where all `Parent`s are fetched and serialized as JSON or XML

```
//Parent Controller
import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.converters.XML
def index() {
        JSON.use('deep')
        render Parent.all as JSON

        //XML.use('deep')
        //render Parent.all as XML
    }
```

**Inference:**
Grails converters can also be used for normal POGO object graphs and are not only confined to domain objects. You can either write the response to an *out stream*, *log appender* or to *an  http response*, you could achieve the deep serialization of the object graph from root to leaf node in all cases.

The example mentioned in [above](http://pastebin.com/3iRerzFF) would make it clear as to how the out format would look like.

*Sample apps written and tested using **Grails 2.2.2**.*

Comment: Great answer, so I am awarding the bounty to you. I did not mention the Grails version in use, but it appears that the deep converters [are now deprecated](http://grails.org/Converters+Reference) in 2.x. Once I removed `JSON.use('deep')`, this worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @PegLeg3941 I have not used deep converter. I have used normal converter with `deep` config. You will need that line definitely, otherwise you will not get what you want. I know deep converters are deprecated. They go by `grails.converters.deep.JSON`. Keep a note on the import statements. Try to run a sample project without `JSON.use` you will not get recursive properties. BTW all of my samples are written and tested in Grails 2.2.2. :)

Comment: @PegLeg3941 Also see the result in each of the sample in deatail it does recursively show each of the property. I highly doubt you will get an object graph till the leaf node serialized properly if `JSON.use('deep')` is not used. Again do visit the samples line by line. :)

Comment: @PegLeg3941 [The link you provided for deprecated deep converter](http://grails.org/Converters+Reference) says exactly what I have done. Revisit the **Note:** in the link. Good Luck. :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to set me straight. I updated the question with what happens when I include `JSON.use('deep')` in the code. Without that, most of the data is rendered, but I had not verified that all of the information is there yet. Do you have any thoughts about it?

Comment: @PegLeg3941 I am unable to replicate that error when running [this script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5840584/) in Grails Console (Grails v 2.2.2). Try to run the same toggling the commented part with `as JSON`. `JSON.use('deep')` will be required when associations are involved in domain class. Try to run my first sample where domain objects are used, without deep you will not be able to get to associated domain objects. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Groovy's Object class has a method `dump()`. It described here
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#dump()

I never used it, but hope it will help you.

Comment: The .dump() method seems to call .toString() on the properties of the object. This looks something like: `<com.company.services.provider.DATARESP@1a2a03c2 header=com.company.services.provider.HEADER@5321c1b2 datars=com.company.services.provider.DATARS@b134c6ad fee=null paymentsourcevalue=>`

Comment: Just to clarify: The .dump() method is not recursive at all, so it will not work. Thanks.